# Change Azure B2C subscription

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to change the billing subscription on a Azure B2C tenant. I see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/billing#change-the-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-billing-subscription) article which states: "Azure AD B2C tenants can be moved to another subscription if the source and destination subscriptions exist within the same Azure Active Directory tenant." but I suppose this did not clarify for me.

I have two different subscriptions which are just independant Azure subscriptions and neither is part of a corporate enrollment, so I don't think they are apart of the same AD tenant, unless onmicrosoft is the AD tenant.

Has anybody done this before?

Answer (score 2):

Tenant means .onmicrosoft.com directory. If both subscriptions appear when selecting the directory in the Azure Portal, then the B2C resource can be moved between them. If not, then you first need to move the destination subscription to the tenant in which the subscription that holds the B2C resource lives, move the resource, then move the subscription back to the original tenant if you need to. Moving subscriptions between tenants will lose all RBAC assignments, since they are tied to the users in the original tenant/directory.

Comment: This is helpful and great to hear. Thank you. Now I need to figure out how to move the destination subscription to the tenant. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: I don't see either subscription. I sign in to the one account which created the b2c tenant. I switch to the directory (under user in the upper right of the screen) and then click on subscriptions and none are listed.

Comment: You need to switch to the Azure AD, not the Azure AD B2C directory. AAD B2C never contains a subscription. AAD B2C is a resource like a Virtual Machine, it sits in a Azure Subscription, which is tied to your Azure AD.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't you be able to go into the subscription and see it listed as a resource? I think when I created it, I had to link it to a subscription, but I cannot find a way to transfer it from one subscription to another. The link you provided seems to describe how to transfer a subscription to a different AD directory, and you only seem to be able to have one of those for a subscription. I believe I have two B2C tenants associated with my subscription, but cannot see them in the subscription or see the subscription from either directory.

Comment: You should be able to see all the tenants listed under Your Profile > Switch Directory > All directories. You can also get it via - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list.

Comment: Also, you can use this checklist - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#checklist-before-moving-resources to see if the source and destination subscriptions must exist within the same Azure Active Directory tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I've read the other answers and the comment that helped my find the solution was the one by Jas Suri - MSFT.

If you switch directory and go to the Azure AD B2C resource you will not find the move option.

The way I did it was to go the the subscription containing the B2C tenant resource and there you will find the move button, this was not really obvious.

[image]